# Checking the site collection admins

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Is there any link where we can check the site collection admins if we provide the site adress?

If there is, please help me out with that link.

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the **Admin center** then following are the steps to check the primary site collection admin and other stuffs

For SharePoint online,

- Go to https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal/Home?switchtomoderndefault=true#/homepage
- In left navigation, under **Admin Centers** select SharePoint
- You will see the list of site collections. Click the sitecollection link and popup appears. In popup it will show administrator names and all other details.

[image]

Comment: Will that link be valid for every random user?

Comment: It's not for random users, user who have permissions to view admin center can view this

Comment: SO does pradeep has the access to that page?

Comment: I request down voters, to mention the detailed reason in comment for down voting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the correct permission, you may visit this

```
/_layouts/15/mngsiteadmin.aspx
```

otherwise, it will be access denied

Answer (score 0):

That is so easy.

1. First of all, you yourself should be the Site Collection Administrator.
2. Then click on **Site settings** -> **Users and Permissions** -> **Site Collection Administrators**.
3. Here you can view the list of names of the users who have the Site Administrator permissions.

And https://'your company name'.sharepoint.com/'Site collection'/_layouts/15/mngsiteadmin.aspx is the link which you are looking for.

Comment: refrain from posting duplicate answers.

Comment: @Aventus Look at the time, both were answered at the exact same time. I didn't know what his answer was. Anyway I will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:
https://testSubscription.sharepoint.com/sites/NameOfSiteCollection/_layouts/15/mngsiteadmin.aspx
and
https://testSubscription.sharepoint.com/sites/NameOfSiteCollection/Subsite/_layouts/15/mngsiteadmin.aspx , so

site address +_layouts/15/mngsiteadmin.aspx.

This will lead you to:
[image]

This is universal link that should work with every site collection and every subsite as well.

Comment: Why would you keep on posting duplicate answers?

Comment: Because it took me time to login, make and upload a screenshot and provide an explanation so I didn't notice yours in between. I'd have deleted but I think it offers more information (even on such a simple question) and OP may find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a portal where we can see the site collection admins.

https://mcportal.accenture.com/WebTools/TeamSites/

Please enter the link as mentioned below.

https://ts.accenture.com/sites/(NAME OF THE SHAREPOINT).

And hit enter.

User will get to know the site collection admins.